# how to integrate facebook api in this actionscript code?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i have used this code in my index.php to get user facebook first name last name and userid

```
var flashvars = {fname:fname, lname:lname, birth_date:birth_date, uid:userId, gender:gender, thumb:picture, app_id:"-1", showWarningMessage:showWarningMessage, localLanguage:localLanguage, chatSession:chatSession,
```

i have passed this flashvars in my swf like this `swfobject.embedSWF("swf/tandoochat.swf?rev=" + REVISION, "swf", "760", "451", "9.0.124", "scripts/swfobject/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes, onNoFlash);
}`

i want to know how i can use fname and last name in my actionscript ,can anybody give me simple example ,so i can use fname in myactionscript code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just trying to use the flashvars in Flash, it would look something like:

```
var params:Object = root.loaderInfo.parameters;
trace("first name = " + params.fname);
trace("last name = " + params.lname);
```

I'm not sure how this has to do with the FB api...is this what you're looking for?

Comment: If you are going to make graph api calls, be sure to pass in your facebook access_token as well.